# My app got rejected because lacking " significant account-specific functionality from Google"

Tags: ios, firebase, app-store-connect, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I made an app using firebase and I have implemented Google account based logIn system to my app because I thought it would good and also helps me for Firebase Invites but my app got rejected by the apple app review team and they are telling that I have to implement "significant account-specific functionality from Google".

My app is like a social networking app something similar to Facebook. Users in the app can invite friends, share content with friends to achieve this I used the Firebase features like real-time database, Storage, Firebase Invites etc... I really don't know what else I should implement to eligible for "significant account-specific functionality from Google."

I have sent an email for help but they haven't responded yet.

Comment: Can your app operate without Google account authentication?  If so then you should make logging in to your Google account optional.

Comment: No, it can only log in with google account.

Comment: Using Google should be ok. 1. Have they mention any requirement number in rejection? Please share that. It tells you where you need to make change.

Comment: 5. 1.1 LEGAL: PRIVACY - DATA COLLECTION AND STORAGE

Comment: i have searched all the documentation but couldn't find what are "significant account-specific functionality from Google". https://developers.google.com/terms/

Comment: It seems that firebase supports a number of authentication options other than google login; https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html. Apple is probably saying that your app doesn't have sufficient Google-specific functionality for you to require your users to have a Google account. You can offer your users a range of authentication options, not just google

Comment: do you allow users to use app without login to google ?

Comment: I am trying to figuring out what are "significant account-specific functionality from Google" because according to Firebase Invites docs i must log in the users to enables them to send Firebase Invites. https://firebase.google.com/docs/invites/ios

Comment: No, I can only allow users to log In via google auth because it is mandatory for users to use Firebase Invites.

Comment: The it sounds like, as @AmodGokhale suggests, you should allow e user to use the app anonymously until the point where they want to invite someone. At that point you can require them to log in

Comment: @ilvcs i would recommend to talk to appeal board before making again the architectural change. We are @ their mercy to get it through :(

Comment: I have implemented a "No thanks" button in signIn page which will leads them to main view and i have implemented an alert in the main view which tells to LogIn if they wants to properly use the app. I have submitted for review, lets see whats gonna happen with the reviewing process.

Comment: My app status is "In Review" since 2 days i haven't got any updates or emails from apple team. Is that okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using firebase is perfectly fine in iOS.

5. 1.1 LEGAL: PRIVACY - DATA COLLECTION AND STORAGE -  significant account-based features

Read section ii) https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#data-collection-and-storage

> If your core app functionality is not related to a specific social
>   network (e.g. Facebook, WeChat, Weibo, Twitter, etc.), **you must
>   provide access without a login or via another mechanism.**

Since your app is not using any specific social network feature ( facebook,twitter - which demands a login ) you must allow users to provide functionality without login.

You might want to appeal to Appeal board with explanation why user must login in order to use the app ( give examples and screenshots of specific functionality which cannot be used without login ).

If your appeal is rejected you don't have any option but to redesign the app to follow what apple is suggesting. What we have done in past is provide a basic flow without login but once it reaches point where login is must we force user to login ( something like anonymous user).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same rejection this week because I have a Facebook login.

My app was already live, and this is rejection for an update.

There is a [change in their guideline](http://www.appstorereviewguidelineshistory.com/articles/2016-09-01-subscriptions-siri-kit-stickers/). This is new on Sep 1, 2016:

> If your core app functionality is not related to a specific social network (e.g. Facebook, WeChat, Weibo, Twitter, etc.), you must provide access without a login or via another mechanism. Pulling basic profile information, sharing to the social network, or inviting friends to use the app are not considered core app functionality.

In essence, they are killing many apps that simply use social networks for single sign on.

A solution right now is to implement your own login account mechanism.

Comment: Are they telling you to remove the google/facebook/twitter logon as a SSO, or are they saying you have to provide a standalone option as well. For those who don't have google/facebook/twitter or don't want to use them.

Comment: They did not say need to remove Facebook. But must provide a standalone mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

After 3-4 rejections I found the solution for this problem. I have have implemented a feature called Firebase Invites and for that they must sign in with their Google Account.

According to Appstore guidelines we even can't use third party login for sending invitations. In that situation, I have convinced them that "with this Firebase Invites I can able to see my friends in my Google Account and send them invitations personally". With that answer (they called me by phone) it seems they have convinced and accepted my app.